# composer install fails with class not found

Tags: php, laravel

I cloned project from git then when I want to do composer install or update this error is coming

> In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
> Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' not found

> Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
> PS D:\klizos\newpiedparker_backend\newpiedparker.com> php artisan clear

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

> Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' not found

```
PS D:\klizos\newpiedparker_backend\newpiedparker.com> composer require illuminate/auth
Using version ^8.49 for illuminate/auth
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update illuminate/auth
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires illuminate/auth ^8.49, found illuminate/auth[v8.49.0, v8.49.1, v8.49.2, 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
PS D:\klizos\newpiedparker_backend\newpiedparker.com> php artisan make:model t


  Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' not found
```

Comment: You can try installing Tymon\JWTAuth before composer install or update and then run composer install!

Answer (score 0):

Try running below commands:

```sh
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
composer install
```

But before that, maybe ensure `package.json` file contains something like:

```json
{

    // ...

    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```